# Select Condicional com outro Select

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou usando SQL Oracle. Eu preciso retornar um Select que dependendo do valor da coluna GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID (precisa ser igual a 87) ele deve executar um Select, senão ele deve executar outro select... Acredito que estou próximo do que eu preciso, mas dispara um erro que que uma palavra-chave nao foi encontrada... O que estou fazendo de errado??

```
select CASE GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID
       WHEN ((select GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID from empresa where codigo = :TOKEN) = 87)
           THEN
               (SELECT emp.id
                from empresa emp
                where emp.grupo_economico_id = 87
                union
                SELECT emp.id
                from empresa emp
                WHERE codigo = (vou chumbar um token aqui ainda a ser criado, mas ele e diferente dos outros TOKENs aqui descritos)
           ELSE
               (SELECT emp.id
                FROM empresa emp
                WHERE emp.grupo_economico_id = (
                    SELECT grupo_economico_id
                    FROM empresa
                    WHERE codigo = :TOKEN
                ))
           END as total from empresa;
```

Comment: `where codigo = :TOKEN) = 87` este `where` não deveria ser `where GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID  = 87`?

Comment: Creio que não por que esse cara faz uma pesquisa na tabela empresa pelo token que foi passado pelo usuário e ai poderá retornar 87... Então a condicional vem do (select GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID from empresa where codigo = :TOKEN)

Comment: Confuso , ao menos para mim , poderia dar um exemplo com dados ?

Comment: Claro a ideia é que ao pesquisar sobre uma empresa X, o usuário recebe a informação de todas as empresas que pertencem ao mesmo grupo econômico dessa empresa X, certo? O que acontece e que existe um regra de select especifica para quando especificamente o grupo econômico for 87, então eu preciso de algum tipo de condicional (IF.. ELSE serve tambem) dentro do sql oracle para executar um select ou outro dependendo do grupo econômico (especificamente o 87).

Answer (score 0):

No caso acho que o que está lhe atrapalhando seria indicar um campo na frente do CASE, o oracle permite fazer um case sem indicar essa chave.

```
select CASE 
       WHEN ((select GRUPO_ECONOMICO_ID from empresa where codigo = :TOKEN) = 87)
           THEN
               (SELECT emp.id
                from empresa emp
                where emp.grupo_economico_id = 87
                union
                SELECT emp.id
                from empresa emp
                WHERE codigo = (vou chumbar um token aqui ainda a ser criado, mas ele e diferente dos outros TOKENs aqui descritos)
           ELSE
               (SELECT emp.id
                FROM empresa emp
                WHERE emp.grupo_economico_id = (
                    SELECT grupo_economico_id
                    FROM empresa
                    WHERE codigo = :TOKEN
                ))
           END as total from empresa;
```

Como está indicando o campo na frente do CASE, o oracle espera que seja uma comparação simples com essa chave, não consegui simular por preguiça de criar uma base de dados parecida.

Espero que ajude!